# How to dynamically change palette type (dark/light) of theme using Switch and withStyles()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to create a switch that changes the dark mode of the site. It somewhat works with changing the text color. However, the background and everything else stays the same, even with CssBaseline

Here is the important code:

App.tsx

```js
class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  curTheme: Theme;
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      theme: ThemeManagerInstance
    };

    this.curTheme = createMuiTheme(this.state.theme.getTheme);
  }


  render() {
    const classes = this.props.classes;
    this.curTheme = createMuiTheme(this.state.theme.getTheme);

    console.log("Dark status: " + (this.isDark()));

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={this.getTheme()}>
          <CssBaseline />
                 <FormControlLabel
                    control={
                      <Switch
                        checked={this.isDark()}
                        onChange={() => {
                          this.setState(state => {
                            this.state.theme.useDarkMode(
                              !this.isDark()
                            );
                            //   this.state.theme.getTheme().palette.type === // if (
                            //   "dark"
                            // ) {
                            //   this.state.theme.getTheme().palette.type =
                            //     "light";
                            // } else {
                            //   this.state.theme.getTheme().palette.type = "dark";
                            // }

                            console.log(this.getTheme().palette.type);

                            return state;
                          });
                        }}
                        color="primary"
                        value="dynamic-class-name"
                      />
                    }
                    label="Dark Mode"
                  />
          {/* code goes here */}
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }



  getTheme() {
    return this.curTheme;
  }

  isDark() {
    return this.getTheme().palette.type === "dark"
  }
}

// export default App;

export default withStyles(
  styleJSON(createMuiTheme(ThemeManagerInstance.getTheme))
)(App);
```

theme.tsx

```js
import blue from "@material-ui/core/colors/blue";
import createMuiTheme, {
  Theme,
  ThemeOptions
} from "@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme";
import { PaletteOptions } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette";
import { PaletteType } from "@material-ui/core";

const palette: PaletteOptions = {
  primary: {
    main: "#1976D2"
  },
  type: "light"
};

const defaultTheme = {
  palette: palette
};

export class ThemeManager {
  constructor(private theme: ThemeOptions) {
    this.useDarkMode(true);

    console.log(this.getTheme);
  }

  getThemePalette(): PaletteOptions | undefined {
    return this.theme.palette;
  }

  get getTheme() {
    return this.theme;
  }

  useDarkMode(dark: boolean) {
    const typeColor: PaletteType = dark ? "dark" : "light";

    const updatedTheme: ThemeOptions = {
      ...this.theme,
      palette: {
        ...this.theme.palette,
        type: typeColor
      }
    };

    this.theme = updatedTheme;
  }
}

const themeInstance = new ThemeManager(defaultTheme);

export default themeInstance;
```

index.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    < App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Excuse me if it sounds like I'm asking for sponefeeding code, but I'm honestly stumped since I don't understand how to handle reloading style info from withStyles()

Comment: I think your main issue is state management. `useDarkMode` doesn't call `setState` so it isn't going to trigger a re-render. You have a strange mix of instance variables (e.g. `this.theme`, `this.curTheme`) and state that makes it difficult to reason about the correctness of the code. I recommend converting to function components (so that you **can't** use instance variables) and have a single boolean state variable for the switch (dark vs light) and then a function to create the theme based on that boolean. I think the end result will be much simpler to understand and eliminate your issue.

Comment: Yeah excuse my ugly code, I’ve just been trying new solutions for a while and I usually leave ugly or inconsistent code behind. I’ll work on that when I get on my setup

Answer (score 0):

can try this
https://github.com/bluelovers/ws-react/tree/master/packages/material-ui-theme-state

```
import { useTheme, createTheme } from 'material-ui-theme-state/esm/global';
```

create theme

```
let bool = prefersLightMode();
let theme: ThemeOptions | Theme;
    let setTheme: IThemeExtra["setTheme"];

    ([theme, setTheme] = useState({
        palette: {
            type: bool ? 'light': 'dark',
        },
        //direction: 'rtl'
    }));
const muiTheme = createTheme(theme, {
        setTheme,
    }).theme;

    return (<MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>{props.children}</MuiThemeProvider>)
```

any other u wana change theme

```
const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();

setTheme(theme => {

                theme.palette.type = (theme.palette.type !== 'light') ? 'light' : 'dark';

            return theme;
        }, true)
```

live demo
https://tpl-next-app.now.sh/

Comment: Well my main problem I believe is that my App component is being styled at the export which is ```

export default withStyles(
  styleJSON(createMuiTheme(ThemeManagerInstance.getTheme))
)(App);

```